# Getting UTF-8 encoded from US-ASCII encoded string

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a string "ChÃ¢teau" with UTF-8 encoded & it gets converted to US-ASCII format as "Ch??teau"(in the underlying lib of my app)

Now, I want to get the original string "ChÃ¢teau" back from "U-ASCII" converted string "Ch??teau". But, I am not able to get that using the below code.

```
StringBuilder masterBuffer = new StringBuilder();
byte[] rawDataBuffer = (Read from InputStream) // say here it is "ChÃ¢teau"
String rawString = new String(rawDataBuffer, "UTF-8");
masterBuffer.append(rawString);
onMessageReceived(masterBuffer.toString().getBytes()) => Here, getBytes() uses the platform's default charset 'US-ASCII.
```

My application receives the byte array of US-ASCII encoded. 
On application side, even if I try to get UTF-8 string out of it, it's of no use.
The conversion attempt still gives "Ch??teau".

```
String asciiString = "Ch??teau";
String originalString = new String(asciiString.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");
System.out.println("orinalString: " + originalString);
```

The value of 'originalString" is still "Ch??teau".

Is this right way to do this ?

Thanks,

Comment: OK, so, first things first: **there. is. no. such. thing. as. a. UTF-8. encoded. String**. Java `String`s store text data regardless of the character coding, and this means that your problem lies beyond the code you posted. Please paste the full code.

Comment: @fge Java's `String` (like C#'s, JavaScript's, …) is a counted sequence of UTF-16 code units, one or two of which encode a Unicode codepoint. (And, there are apparently characters in the computer world that aren't in the Unicode characters set.)

Comment: @TomBlodget: in the upcoming Java 9 next year, strings will not always store UTF-16 internally anymore. [They will use ISO-8859-1 instead](https://www.voxxed.com/blog/2015/11/london-java-community-holds-strong-in-jcp-election/) to compact memory usage when possible. Of course, public interfaces would still expect `char` and `String` methods to act on UTF-16 data, so there would have to be additional conversions performed at runtime to facilitate ISO-8859-1 based strings in UTF-16 based code logic.

Comment: @TomBlodget but that's an implementation detail. For all it's worth, elements of a `String` could be carrier pigeons; a `String` has no encoding.

Comment: @fge Not quite. It would be ideal if code that uses string was written that way but as soon as you take the length or use an index or other `char` related operation you have to deal with how many UTF-16 code units in each individual Unicode codepoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  You lost information by converting to US-ASCII. You can't get back what was lost.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is receiving a UTF-8 encoded byte array, *correctly* converting it to a Java `String`, but is then converting that string to an ASCII encoded byte array.  ASCII does not support the `Ã` and `¢` characters, which is why they are being converted to `?`.  Once that conversion has been done, there is no going back.  ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, and `?` in ASCII is also `?` in UTF-8.

The solution is to stop converting to ASCII to begin with.  You should convert back to UTF-8 instead:

```
StringBuilder masterBuffer = new StringBuilder();
byte[] rawDataBuffer = ...; // Read from InputStream
String rawString = new String(rawDataBuffer, "UTF-8");
masterBuffer.append(rawString);
onMessageReceived(masterBuffer.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

At least that way, for true ASCII characters, the receiver will never know the difference (since ASCII is a subset of UTF-8), and non-ASCII character will not be lost anymore.  The receiver just needs to know to expect UTF-8 and not ASCII.  And, your code will be more portable, since you will no longer be dependent on a platform-specific default charset (not all platforms use ASCII by default).

Of course, in your example, your `StringBuilder` is redundant since you are not adding anything else to it, so you could just remove it:

```
byte[] rawDataBuffer = ...; // Read from InputStream
String rawString = new String(rawDataBuffer, "UTF-8");
onMessageReceived(rawString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

And then the `String` becomes redundant, too:

```
byte[] rawDataBuffer = ...; // Read from InputStream
onMessageReceived(rawDataBuffer);
```

If `onMessageReceived()` expects bytes as input, why waste overhead converting bytes to String to bytes again?

Comment: "The solution is to stop converting to ASCII to begin with" => It happens in underlying third-party library on which I don't have control. That's the problem. That's why I wanted to get UTF-8 string out of US-ASCII encoded byte array(@app level). Looks like, that's not possible.